# Realm object not accesible when realm is closed. Android

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm for Android.

I have issue (not really a big problem), I have this lines of code:

```
Account account;
....
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
account = realm.where(Account.class).findFirst();
realm.close();
if (account.getJid().equals(mUser.getText().toString())) { // User is the same as logged before
    launchLogin(mUser.getText().toString().split("@")[0],mPassword.getText().toString());

}
```

If I launch the app, when the execution arrives to IF statement, it crash because `account` object does'nt exist. Even when exist accounts in the db.
But If move the `realm.close()` inside the IF, after the launchLogin(..), it works .

What I understand is that account "dissapears" when I close the realm db. and I can get real problem in a future.

So I want to know how can I made "persistent" this type of problem. I mean, close realm after queries and the object still exist after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to EpicPandaForces answer, if you really want to close the realm and discard any auto-update advantages Realm offers, you can create an unmanaged copy of the `RealmObject` using `realm.copyFromRealm(realmObject);`

Comment: I always feel iffy about copying elements out of a zero-copy database, which is why I specifically didn't include the option of using `copyFromRealm` in my answer. :P But yes, that also "solves" the immediate problem.

Comment: Hmm.. OK, I understand. What really need for this activity is to verify I the account exist (just supposed to be 1 at time.maybe in a future more.), thats Why I don't need the "auto-update" feature. But I'll take in consideration @EpicPandaForce answer  for nex features. Thanks mates

Answer (score 2):

Managed RealmObject instances can only be accessed from Realm instances that are not closed.

[Following the official documentation, you should have an open instance for the UI thread bound to the lifecycle of the application itself.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances)

From the docs:

```
// onCreate()/onDestroy() overlap when switching between activities so onCreate()
// on Activity 2 will be called before onDestroy() on Activity 1.

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

And

```
// Use onCreateView()/onDestroyView() for Fragments as onDestroy() might not be called.
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

---

And for background threads:

```
// Run a non-Looper thread with a Realm instance.
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            // ... Use the Realm instance ...
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

---

---

Following the docs, the problem you mention won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to open the Realm instance at the beginning of the background thread, close it at the end of execution in that background thread,

```
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    account = realm.where(Account.class).findFirst();

    if (account.getJid().equals(mUser.getText().toString())) { // User is the same as logged before
        launchLogin(mUser.getText().toString().split("@")[0],mPassword.getText().toString());

    } 
} finally {
     if(realm != null) {
          realm.close(); // important 
     } 
}
```